# Eclipse Plugin Development : Document Validator for text editor and MultiLineRule

Tags: java, eclipse, validation, eclipse-plugin

So today I have two questions :

1. I want to develop a document validator for text editor and as I generated Eclipse Plugin with a generic editor it is creating a validator for XML and I wand to change it to text editor. Does someone know how?

   ```
           DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
           documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(reader));
       } catch (Exception ex) {
           try {
               if (this.marker != null)
                   this.marker.delete();
               this.marker = file.createMarker(IMarker.PROBLEM);
               this.marker.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_WARNING);
               this.marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, "nadav");
               // if (ex instanceof SAXParseException) {
               // SAXParseException saxParseException = (SAXParseException)ex;
               // int lineNumber = saxParseException.getLineNumber();
               // int offset = event.getDocument().getLineInformation(lineNumber -
               // 1).getOffset() + saxParseException.getColumnNumber() - 1;
               // this.marker.setAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, lineNumber);
               // this.marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START, offset);
               // this.marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END, offset + 1);
               // }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               // e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   ```

   Here its just parsing the document as XML and this is what the eclipse genrated for me.
2. I have line rules as SingleLineRule and WordRule but my problem is with the MultiLineRule because it doesn't seem like a MultiLine after 2 lines (3 or more) it doesn't match it. What can i do with it?
   Here is my code:

   ```
   RuleBasedScanner scanner = new RuleBasedScanner();
   IRule[] rules = new IRule[5];
   rules[2] = new SingleLineRule("\"", "\"", new Token(stringAttribute));
   rules[3] = new MultiLineRule("/*", "*/", new Token(commentAttribute));
   rules[4] = new SingleLineRule("//", null, new Token(commentAttribute));
   rules[1] = new NumberRule(new Token(number));
   WordRule rule = new WordRule(new IWordDetector() {

       @Override
       public boolean isWordStart(char c) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           return Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(c);
       }

       @Override
       public boolean isWordPart(char c) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           return Character.isLetterOrDigit(c);
       }
   }, new Token(new TextAttribute(new Color(Display.getCurrent(), new RGB(0, 0, 0)))), true);
   for (int i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
       if(keywords[i].equals("#define") || keywords[i].equals("#include"))
           rule.addWord(keywords[i].toLowerCase(), new Token(define));
       else
           rule.addWord(keywords[i].toLowerCase(), new Token(wordAttribute));
   }
   rules[0] = rule;
   scanner.setRules(rules);
   DefaultDamagerRepairer dr = new DefaultDamagerRepairer(scanner);
   this.setDamager(dr, IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
   this.setRepairer(dr, IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
   ```

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in a single question, it make it hard for people to answer. If you are talking about the sample XML editor generated by the New Project template I don't think it includes a document validator. For MultiLineRule you need to show us your code and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: @greg-449 here is my code. Are you familiar with the problem?

Comment: @greg-449 Are you familiar with the problem?

Comment: I already said you need to ask separate questions about these two problems and explain them more clearly. I don't understand what question 1 is asking at all.

Comment: @greg-449 Can you answer question 2?

Comment: I am not aware of any problems with MultiLineRule